# Determine If An Element Is An Image Using Jquery In CKEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to determine if an element if an image or not using jQuery. This should be straightforward using `$('selector').is('img')`, but that's not working. Here is a screenshot from Chrome's watch expression console. I don't understand why the is() function is failing. The debugger says the element is an HTMLImageElement. Any suggestions?

```
var selectedElement = ckEditor.getSelection().getSelectedElement();
var $element = $(selectedElement);
var isImage = $element.is('img');
```

[image]

Comment: The first "element" in the set is inside another wrapper, of which the `$` property is the actual element. What other libraries are you using?

Comment: I'm getting the element from CKEditor's API getSelectedElement() and then wrapping it in a jQuery set. Would this make a difference?

Comment: Seems like it should work.  http://jsfiddle.net/X2nmM/  Can you create a broken example?

Comment: Do you also want to elements like <input type="image" /> to be returned as image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.dom.selection.html#getSelectedElement) says that `.getSelectedElement()` returns an instance of `CKEDITOR.dom.element` and not a native DOM element. So when calling jQuery, you're wrapping another wrapper, which doesn't play nicely - jQuery doesn't know how to deal with those CKEditor objects. What the documentation also says is that the `$` property is the native DOM element, so:

```
var $element = $(selectedElement.$);
```

Comment: Seems like this is the case. According to the same docs, I think you can also do `selectedElement.is('img')` right away: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.dom.element.html#is

Comment: @David: Hmm yes, that library has alot of jQuery's functionality. But it may be cleaner to stay with using one library.

Comment: @pimvdb Thank you!. I'm fairly new to to CKEditor so that is a huge help!

Comment: @David I like this approach. I'm using it in the code now and it's working. Thank you!

Comment: In my case every time I'm getting a div, for text for images results are same and its a div. Any idea?